# After deleting a big file the space isn't freed even after rebooting the system:

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, fedora, gnome

So I have that problem. The space hasn't been freed, either checking by GUI (Nautilus or Disks utility) or by TUI(df). I've read that it could be because another process was still handling the file when deleted, so you've removed the link but the file is still somewhere deep in the filesystem. Of course, I tried the lsof commands and other solutions, but I couldn't find the deleted file. I also read that once the process which was handling the file when deleted is killed, the file is released and thus, the space is freed in the disk. However, when I rebooted my computer, all processes had been killed, so the space should be freed, but it never happened. So how can I find that file and remove it?

Thanks in advanced. PD: I'm using Fedora 36 with GNOME.

Comment: What filesystem was the large file on?  How did you delete it?  Are you sure it wasn't completely deleted and only moved to a trash folder somewhere?

Comment: That file was at the /home partition in ~, and I deleted the trash several times. However, it took too little for the size of the file.

Comment: By "filesystem", I meant, for example, `ext4`, `XFS`, `btrfs`, etc..  If `/home` resides on `btrfs` formatted partition, are you using/making snapshots?